# How to cross check two lines of a text file with Python

Tags: python

I am reading lines from a text file and trying to check if a line has the word "open" in it. If the line has the word "open" in it, it will be left but if it does not have the word "open" in it, the line is written to another file.

For example

```html
We open the door
I walked through the door
```

In the example above the sentence 'We open the door' would not be considered but the sentence 'I walked through the door' would be written to another file.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to understand what exactly you are wanting, but I think you are wanting something like this

```
with open('nopen.txt','w') as not_open_file, open('infile.txt','r') as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        if 'open' not in line:
            not_open_file.write(line)  # file with lines that do not have open
```

if you are worried about people living in Copenhagen (or other partial word matching)

```
with open('nopen.txt','w') as not_open_file, open('infile.txt','r') as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        if 'open' not in [word.lower() for word in re.split(r'\W+', line)]:
            not_open_file.write(line)  # file with lines that do not have open
```

Comment: This is probably too simplistic. Try your solution with the string `"I live in Copenhagen."` However, using `re.split(r'\W+', line)` instead of `line` would probably be sufficient. You might also want to convert the whole line to lowercase so you can match `'Open'` too.

Comment: Bah, who lives in Copenhagen!! (kidding) added examples for that

Comment: I actually live in Houston, but _Copenhagen_ was the only word/name I could think of off the top of my head that had _open_ in it.

Comment: I actually live in Copenhagen :)

Comment: I also live in Copenhagen :)